# Nginx rewrite http to https and proxy to another port, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy

Trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy here. This is what I want to achieve:

- Redirect `example.com` and `www.example.com` to `https://example.com`.
- Proxy the request to another port.

This is the flow: `example.com` -> `Nginx` -> `Go web server listening on port 5000`

It seems that the rewriting is working properly, cause in the browser I get `https://example.com`, however I am getting this error in the browser:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

If it matters, my DNS settings are as such:

```
@   - A - 11.XX.XX.XX
www - A - 11.XX.XX.XX
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen      80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$request_uri permanent;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        listen      [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem";

        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://example.com$request_uri permanent;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Networking noob here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other two answers were very helpful in fixing the answer to this question (Redirect loop). There was another bug however, which is that the www was showing up every time even though I redirected to non-www https version.

Here is the updated config that does the following:

- Turn www to non-www
- Turn http to https

  ```
  events {
      worker_connections 1024;
  }

  http {
      server {
          listen      80;
          listen      [::]:80;
          server_name www.example.com example.com;

          return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
      }

      server {
          listen      443 ssl;
          listen      [::]:443 ssl;
          server_name www.example.com;

          ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem";
          ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem";

          return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
      }

      server {
          listen      443 ssl;
          listen      [::]:443 ssl;
          server_name example.com;

          ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem";
          ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem";

          location / {
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

In this `server` block, just redirect to HTTPS block, no need a `location` block here:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to add the redirection 443 block as it is already redirected from 80 block. So try the following configuration:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen      80;
        listen      [::]:80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen      443 ssl;
        listen      [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem";
        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem";



        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }
}
```